# Why are dates in pandas being displayed in a different format to input (CSV) data?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV which has dates in this format:

```
Date
01/01/1997
02/01/1997
03/01/1997
04/01/1997
```

I am importing the data into a dataset using `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`

**When I look at the data held in the dataframe it appears in a different format:**

```
df['Date']


Date
1997-1-1
1997-1-2
1997-1-3
1997-1-4
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

I've tried Googling & looking on SOF but haven't been able to find the answer...

Comment: What does `df["Date"].dtype` show?  I believe `pandas` has automatically recognized that this column contains dates and converted them to `datetype` objects.  You may wish to keep `df["Date"]` in this format, however, and do what @DeepSpace suggested below.  Or add `dtype={"Date" : str}` to your `read_csv()` call to keep these values unchanged (and as strings).

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is the ISO 8601 date format.  http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm

Comment: @dmn `df['Date'].dtype` gives `dtype('O')` ?? If I pass `dtype={'GMT': str}` I still get `dtype('O')`

Comment: @VinylWarmth that's ok.  When you pass in `dtype={"GMT" : str}` do the dates look the way you want them to?

Comment: `dtype('O')` - means 'object' (or string in pandas terminology)

Comment: Is anyone able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's `pandas` default time format.

You can pass `read_csv` `dayfirst=True`, as can be seen in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> dayfirst : boolean, default False
>   DD/MM format dates, international and European format

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why the same isn't happening for another dataset? In the other dataset the CSV looks like `12/02/2006` and in pandas it looks the same: `12/02/2006`

Comment: @VinylWarmth Try what @dmn suggested in the comments on both the datasets. It is possible that in the second case the column type is `str` and not `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `parse_dates` option from `read_csv` to get data in same format as on your .csv file. Key is `dayfirst=True` to get dates first then month and you can change accordingly. 
You can also change the format as below:

```
df.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
```

For  further readings, refer the documentation http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/

Comment: @VinylWarmth please verify the answer if this worked for you .